# Allow only local connections to LDAP (Port 389) using Windows Firewall with Advanced Security

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

I have two servers that are IBM Lotus Notes Mail Servers and domain controllers with two NIC's, one with a LAN IP and one with a WAN IP.

My client wants all ports to be open, with the exception of blocking LDAP port 389 to WAN requests because a security scan reported LDAP port 389 is listening from the WAN IP address.

I only see a scenario where Windows Firewall with Advanced Security blocks all ports with exceptions, not allow all ports with exceptions.

The client doesn't want to open ports with rules, they want to block ports with rules.

Is that even possible with Windows Firewall with Advaned Security?

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible, at least on Vista/2008 and higher.

1) Create rule that allows everything (custom rule, any protocol, allow, etc)
2) Create a rule that denies port 389

I would however advise approaching them about why they feel this step is necessary, as it does create what most experienced admin would consider an unacceptable level of intrusion risk.